# SAAJ0539/SAAJ0540: disagreement between Spring-WS 1.0.4 and SAAJ in JDK 1.6.0_29

Tags: java, spring-ws, saaj

Working at a large company with long-lived branches and not enough continuous integration, I recently switched to a newer branch (i.e., one in which other groups have been doing a fair bit of development and making a fair number of changes behind my back) and found that trying to start my application, I get the error message below, over and over again in the logs, and no working application.

```
Dec 20, 2011 2:55:16 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl
saveChanges
SEVERE: SAAJ0540: Error during saving a multipart message
Error
  DOMSource cannot be processed: check that saxon8-dom.jar is on the classpath
Dec 20, 2011 2:55:17 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl
saveChanges
SEVERE: SAAJ0539: Unable to get header stream in saveChanges
```

It looks as though `saveChanges()` is being called from `writeTo(SOAPMEssage, OutputStream)` in `org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.Saaj13Implementation`.

`saxon8.jar` is in `WEB-INF/lib`, and so are `saaj-1.2.jar`, `saaj-api-1.3.jar`, and `saaj-impl-1.3.jar`, but as far as I can tell in the debugger, the offending class is in the JDK's `rt.jar`.

I suspect some sort of JAR versioning / classpath ordering error but don't know where to start trying to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solved" the problem by eliminating a dependency on [Nux](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/nux/). Still don't know what the real issue was.